# Calculate the sum of two form fields with javascript?

Tags: forms, javascript

Hello there i was wondering if anyone had the solution to a problem i am having with my  Custom Module. I created a custom form a few days ago and i need two or more(4) field values to be added together and the sum to be output in another field(total).Please not i am using form_panels here s snippet of how the fields are built.

```
$form['Contract']['twelfth'] = array(
 '#type' => 'textfield',
 '#title' => t('Plus FEE of:'),
 '#size' => 40,
 '#field_prefix' => "$",
 '#form_panel_row' => 7,
 '#form_panel_col' => 1
);
$form['Contract']['thirteenth'] = array(
 '#type' => 'textfield',
 '#title' => t('For a OTHER PRICE of:'),
 '#size' => 30,
 '#field_prefix' => "$",
 '#form_panel_row' => 7,
 '#form_panel_col' => 3
);
$form['Contract']['fourteenth'] = array(
 '#type' => 'textfield',
 '#title' => t('For a TOTAL PRICE of:'),
 '#size' => 40,
 '#default_value' => "",
 '#field_prefix' => "$",
 '#form_panel_row' => 8,
 '#form_panel_col' => 1
 );
```

now how can i insert Jquery or Javascipt into this form to calculate those two fields together?

Answer (score 1):

**Replace** your code to next:

```
<?php
  $form['Contract']['twelfth'] = array(
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#title' => t('Plus FEE of:'),
   '#size' => 40,
   '#field_prefix' => "$",
   '#form_panel_row' => 7,
   '#form_panel_col' => 1,
   '#attributes' => array(
      'class' => array('summable'),
    ),
  );
  $form['Contract']['thirteenth'] = array(
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#title' => t('For a OTHER PRICE of:'),
   '#size' => 30,
   '#field_prefix' => "$",
   '#form_panel_row' => 7,
   '#form_panel_col' => 3
   '#attributes' => array(
      'class' => array('summable'),
    ),
  );
  $form['Contract']['fourteenth'] = array(
   '#type' => 'textfield',
   '#title' => t('For a TOTAL PRICE of:'),
   '#size' => 40,
   '#default_value' => "",
   '#field_prefix' => "$",
   '#form_panel_row' => 8,
   '#form_panel_col' => 1
   '#attributes' => array(
      'id' => 'totalsum',
    ),
    '#js' => array(drupal_get_path('module', 'YOURCUSTOMMODULE') . '/js/custom.js'),
   );
?>
```

Don't forget rename YOURCUSTOMMODULE to your module name. 

Create custom.js in your module path/js folder:
**custom.js:**

```
(function ($) {

Drupal.behaviors.custom = {
  attach: function (context) {
    $('input.summable').keyup(function() {
      var sum = 0;
      $('input.summable').each(function() { sum += parseFloat(this.value); });
      $('#totalsum').val(sum);
    });
  }
};

})(jQuery);
```

p.s. **Don't forget** add summing code for inputs in submit function of your form in drupal module, since user can disable JS in browser.

Comment: I added the code and made the changes i think but its not working :/ ..... does this code load on page load or after submission because i need it to work when the page loads?

Comment: does it calculate on key press on any textfield except total after adding code?

Comment: nope nothing happens after adding it. i type into my textfields but get no output anywhere..i have my custom js in a seperate file and all. what could i be doing wrong?

Comment: Did you create custom.js in yourmodulepath/js folder? If it's there, check in browser source, is custom.js appear there in head part...

Comment: not appearing in the header i jus get the beginning script type='text/javascript' but no other idicators. also the input id stays the same on the ltotal field instead of inheriting the "totalsum" id

Comment: Can you show me form code and full html source of you page?

Comment: i got it to half work now. it was the '#js' => (drupal_get_path('module', 'YOURCUSTOMMODULE') . '/js/custom.js'), wasnt adding the script properly i added drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path('module','my_module') . '/js/my_module.js'); but now i get "Uncaught TypeError: Object NaN has no method 'val"

Comment: that I wrote in uppercase, should be replaced by your code, YOURCUSTOMMODULE - replace to your module name.

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Object NaN has no method 'val"  - ? what's that 'val ? in code $('#totalsum').val(sum); should be

Comment: got it to work i had (this.value) wasnt set correctly the first time.thx :) is there a way i can hide "NaN" in the value box? or can i set it at least so the fields are integer only?(currently my_module is the name of my module. stupid but it works for now)

Comment: add code to js and check via http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_isnan.asp